# How can I resolve Error in Maven Java using Netbeans

Tags: java, maven

I am getting following error in project build:

> Failed to execute goal on project records: Could not resolve dependencies for project records:records:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: JavaLibrary2:lp:jar:2, com.freeware.gridtag:dbgrid:jar:1.0.4: JavaLibrary2:lp:jar:2 was not found in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of repository.jboss.org-public has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Please help.

```xml
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>
        4.0.0
    </modelVersion>
    <groupId>
        records
    </groupId>
    <artifactId>
        records
    </artifactId>
    <version>
        0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    </version>
    <packaging>
        war
    </packaging>
    <name>
        admin5_postgres2
    </name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>
            UTF-8
        </project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>
            UTF-8
        </project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework.version>
            4.2.1.RELEASE
        </org.springframework.version>
        <org.hibernate.version>
            4.1.10.Final
        </org.hibernate.version>
        <org.slf4j.version>
            1.5.8
        </org.slf4j.version>
        <deploy.path.name>
            c:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\webapps
        </deploy.path.name>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
            Tomcat
        </netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>
                repository.jboss.org-public
            </id>
            <name>
                JBoss repository
            </name>
            <url>
                https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public
            </url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>
                maven2-repository.dev.java.net
            </id>
            <name>
                Java.net Repository for Maven
            </name>
            <url>
                https://download.java.net/maven/2/
            </url>
            <layout>
                default
            </layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>
                central
            </id>
            <name>
                Central Repository
            </name>
            <url>
                https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
            </url>
            <layout>
                default
            </layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>
                    false
                </enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>
                central
            </id>
            <name>
                Central Repository
            </name>
            <url>
                https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
            </url>
            <layout>
                default
            </layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>
                    false
                </enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>
                    never
                </updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>
            admin5
        </finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>
                    org.apache.maven.plugins
                </groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    maven-war-plugin
                </artifactId>
                <version>
                    2.1.1
                </version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes> -->
                    <warSourceDirectory>
                        ${basedir}/WebContent
                    </warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>
                        ${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml
                    </webXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/web.xml
                    </packagingExcludes>
                    <outputDirectory>
                        ${deploy.path.name}
                    </outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>
                    org.apache.maven.plugins
                </groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    maven-compiler-plugin
                </artifactId>
                <version>
                    2.3.2
                </version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>
                        1.8
                    </source>
                    <target>
                        1.8
                    </target>
                    <executable>
                        ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac
                    </executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- RESOURCES -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>
                    ${basedir}/src/main/resources
                </directory>
                <filtering>
                    true
                </filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.poi
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                poi
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                3.11
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.poi
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                poi-ooxml
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                3.11-beta2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-context
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>
                        commons-logging
                    </groupId>
                    <artifactId>
                        commons-logging
                    </artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework.security
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-security-core
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                4.2.1.RELEASE
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-context-support
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                3.0.5.RELEASE
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-web
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-aspects
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-orm
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-test
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
            <scope>
                test
            </scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-tx
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-webmvc
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                4.2.1.RELEASE
            </version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>
                        commons-logging
                    </groupId>
                    <artifactId>
                        commons-logging
                    </artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-core
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.springframework.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                junit
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                junit
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                4.8.2
            </version>
            <scope>
                test
            </scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                javax.servlet
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                servlet-api
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.5
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Commons Fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                commons-fileupload
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                commons-fileupload
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.3.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.commons
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                commons-io
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.3.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.commons
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                commons-vfs2
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.4
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.tiles
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                tiles-core
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.2.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.tiles
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                tiles-jsp
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.2.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                displaytag
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                displaytag
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.1.1
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                taglibs
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                standard
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.1.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.mortbay.jetty
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                javax.servlet
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                5.1.11
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.tiles
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                tiles-servlet
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.2.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.google.guava
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                guava
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                14.0.1
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.tiles
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                tiles-template
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.2.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                javax.servlet
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                jstl
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.1.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.slf4j
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                slf4j-api
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.slf4j.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.slf4j
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                slf4j-log4j12
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.slf4j.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                log4j
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                log4j
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.2.12
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- common library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                commons-lang
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                commons-lang
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.4
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.googlecode.json-simple
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                json-simple
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.1
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                commons-dbcp
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                commons-dbcp
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.2.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate Dependencies Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.hibernate
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                hibernate-core
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.hibernate.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.hibernate
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                hibernate-ehcache
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.hibernate.version}
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.hibernate.javax.persistence
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                hibernate-jpa-2.0-api
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.0.0.Final
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.hibernate
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                hibernate-entitymanager
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                ${org.hibernate.version}
            </version>
            <type>
                jar
            </type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate end -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                javax.transaction
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                jta
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.1
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                javax.mail
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                mail
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.4.1
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
        <version>8.27.0</version>
        
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.fasterxml.jackson.core
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                jackson-databind
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.12.0
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.fasterxml.jackson.core
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                jackson-annotations
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.12.0
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.thoughtworks.xstream
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                xstream
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.springframework.ws
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-ws
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.5.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                mysql
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                mysql-connector-java
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                5.0.8
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                JavaLibrary2
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                lp
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.httpcomponents
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                httpcore
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                4.3.2
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.httpcomponents
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                httpclient
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                4.3.4
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.freeware.gridtag
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                dbgrid
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                1.0.4
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.lowagie
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                itext
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.1.7
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.apache.pdfbox
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                pdfbox
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                2.0.20
            </version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>
                org.postgresql
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>
                postgresql
            </artifactId>
            <version>
                42.2.14.jre6
            </version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please add your pom.xml to your question.

Comment: The error is quite straight forward, JavaLibrary2 is not resolved. I do not know if it is supposed to be in your local maven repository or in a remote one. But wherever it is supposed to be, it is not there.

Comment: Both `com.freeware.gridtag` and `JavaLibrary2` group ids are not in public maven repositories. Find out where they should be, and configure maven to try and get it from there.

Comment: unrelated: update pdfbox to 2.0.26 .